# Checking for a solution in system of inequalities

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

I have a system modeled by the following:

- $S \in [4000000, 4000001, ..., 48000000]$
- $M \in [1, 2, ..., 8]$
- $N \in [8, 9, ..., 86]$
- $R \in [2, 4, 6, 8]$
- $4000000 \le \frac S M \le 16000000$
- $S * N  = 80000000 \cdot M \cdot R$

I want to determine for a given value of $S$ whether or not there is a solution. I have brute forced the problem and determined that the solutions for $S$ are:

$4000000, 5000000, 6000000, 6400000, 7500000, 8000000, 9600000, 10000000, 12000000, 12800000, 15000000, 16000000, 18000000, 19200000, 20000000, 22500000, 24000000, 25000000, 25600000, 28000000, 28800000, 30000000, 32000000, 35000000, 36000000, 37500000, 38400000, 40000000, 42000000, 44800000, 45000000, 48000000$

Is there a way I can arrive at a mathematical formula for what values of $S$ have a solution?